# pass a custom field value from sale order to invoice

Tags: odoo

I need to pass a custom field value from my sale order form view, to invoice lines in invoice form view. Like odoo passes the products details from sale order to invoice lines. What method does odoo use? Is it a on_change() function?

```
def prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None):
    """Prepare the dict of values to create the new invoice for a
       sales order. This method may be overridden to implement custom
       invoice generation (making sure to call super() to establish
       a clean extension chain).

       :param browse_record order: sale.order record to invoice
       :param list(int) line: list of invoice line IDs that must be
                              attached to the invoice
       :return: dict of value to create() the invoice
    """
    order=self.browse(cr,uid,lines,context=context)
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    journal_ids = self.pool.get('account.journal').search(cr, uid,
        [('type', '=', 'sale'), ('company_id', '=', order.company_id.id)],
        limit=1)
    # if not journal_ids:
    #     raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),
    #         _('Please define sales journal for this company: "%s" (id:%d).') % (order.company_id.name, order.company_id.id))
    invoice_vals = {
        'name': order.client_order_ref or '',
        'origin': order.name,
        'type': 'out_invoice',
        'reference': order.client_order_ref or order.name,
        'account_id': order.partner_invoice_id.property_account_receivable.id,
        'partner_id': order.partner_invoice_id.id,
        'journal_id': journal_ids[0],
        'invoice_line': [(6, 0, lines)],
        'currency_id': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
        'comment': order.note,
        'payment_term': order.payment_term and order.payment_term.id or False,
        'fiscal_position': order.fiscal_position.id or order.partner_invoice_id.property_account_position.id,
        'date_invoice': context.get('date_invoice', False),
        'company_id': order.company_id.id,
        'user_id': order.user_id and order.user_id.id or False,
        'section_id' : order.section_id.id,
        'Order' : order.Order
    }

    # Care for deprecated _inv_get() hook - FIXME: to be removed after 6.1
    invoice_vals.update(self._inv_get(cr, uid, order, context=context))
    return invoice_vals
```

I have got up to overriding this method from sale.py. Where should I call this method to pass field values automatically?

Answer (score 2):

For creating "account.invoice" from "sale.order" there is four selection option

- delivered
- all
- percentage
- fixed

I tried a function "`def action_invoice_create(self, grouped=False, final=False):` " using super in inherited sale.order. It works fine for sending a field value from sale.order to account.invoice, when the selection field is "delivered" or "all".

Instead of "`def action_invoice_create(self, grouped=False, final=False):` " I tried with "`def _prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None):`" also. But same happened it's not working for "percentage" and "fixed" selections.

So I used another function "`def _create_invoice(self, order, so_line, amount):`" using super in inherited wizard/sale_make_invoice_advance.py
It propagated the field value from sale.order to account.invoice successfully. I have tested it in debug also.

Is it right way to achieve? or any other way?

Note: I worked on ODOO9

Answer (score 1):

```
@api.v7
def _prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None):
    res=super(Inherit_so, self)._prepare_invoice(cr, uid, order, lines, context=context)
    inv_obj = self.pool.get('account.invoice.line')
    inv_obj.write(cr, uid, lines, {'Order': order.Order.id}, context=context)
    inv_obj.write(cr, uid, lines, {'staff': order.staff.id}, context=context)
    return res
```

override the method from sale.py